# STL namespace problem in Netbeans 6.8 on AIX

Tags: c++, namespaces, aix, netbeans6.8, std

I'm trying to use NetBeans 6.8 on an AIX OS for C++ development.

I continue getting an error message for:

```
using namespace std;
```

even after adding the includes for the STL via

> options -- c/c++ -- code assistance

The error says: "Unable to resolve identifier std"

Is this a bug in the Netbeans 6.8 AIX version? Or am I missing something?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

You can easily enough test if there is no `std` namespace getting included before your `using` directive by adding in

```
namespace std
{
}
```

just before it. If the compiler is now happy then there was no `std` namespace stuff actually included.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I added your suggestion above, and yes, I don't get a compile error now -- what I expected. Then the question still looms how in NetBeans to resolve the STL namespace issue...?

Comment: I'm assuming the `using` directive is part of your own code and so the obvious answer is don't put it in if you are not including any STL headers. Presumably there is a reason you have that line in the first place?